# ZKTeco SC403 Device - How to Programmatically Add Users and Expand SD Card Capacity (help)

Tags: zkteco

I have a ZKTeco SC403 device, and I can manually add an SD card to it, and it works fine. However, I need to expand the capacity to accommodate up to 5000 users programmatically. I have explored various options in Python, such as pyzk, and I can successfully ping the device over Ethernet. Unfortunately, none of the approaches I've tried seem to detect the device properly. The device is connected to my computer via Ethernet, and my Python code doesn't seem to work. Even if it works, it likely won't allow me to add users.

Is there a way to achieve this programmatically, perhaps in C#? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

I used the PYZK library in Python, expecting at least to establish a connection to the device. However, after a bit of research, I discovered that even adding users is not possible through the Python library. That's why I want to do it with C#.